# Should I use Caller and Called arguments or From and To in Twilio callback request body

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am receiving the same information in the following POST body arguments from twilio callback requests:

- Caller and Called
- From and To

I couldn't find any documentation about the first arguments. Are Caller and Called deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To** and **From** should be used.

`Caller` and `Called` are duplication of `From` and `To`. Used for consolidation data for additional info, like `FromCity, FromState, ToCity, ToState` etc. If such data is available.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. For further information, I believe `Caller` and `Called` are legacy parameter names included as backwards compatibility from the first version of the API and deprecated. Recommendation is to use `From` and `To`.